# Sqlite3 / TypeORM - 3000 tables very slow to init. Can it be fixed or is sqlite just not a good fit

Tags: sql, node.js, database, sqlite, typeorm

I'm sorry if its an obvious question, but still wanted to try.

We have a setup, where we have to create almost 3.000 tables on initialize, where each table represents a stock symbol. The reason we create separate tables, is because each table will contain thousands of rows and we would like to keep it simple in terms of structure.

But the downside is that connecting to the database (with TypeORM), is taking up to 20 seconds...

```
export function createCandleEntity(tableName: string): MixedList<any> {
// export function createCandleEntity(tableName: string): EntitySchema<ICandleObject> {
  @Entity({name: tableName})
  class CandleEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    time!: number

    @Column({ nullable: false })
    open: number

    @Column({ nullable: false })
    high: number

    @Column({ nullable: false })
    low: number

    @Column({ nullable: false })
    close: number

    @Column({ nullable: false })
    volume: number
  }

  return CandleEntity
}
```

The table it self is pretty simple, but it really starts to hinder our development process, waiting for it everytime.

I was thinking about pre-checking existing tables, and/or dynamically add entities after database connection, but TypeORM doesn't allow adding entities AFTER init.

So I'm running out of ideas..

Does anyone maybe have a suggestion? Or do you think there are better databases for this.

Thanks!

edit:

using `synchronize: true/false`, seems to fix a lot, but that doesn't create the tables on init and its highly dynamic, so that will leave uncreated tables..

Comment: SQLite is good. The cause is TypeORM. I suppose that TypeORM executes several queries (at least one `create table...` is writtable) per each class. All of them use an individual transaction. Typical SQLite usage is one writer and multiple readers. TypeORM brokes it. When you use `pragma syncronize = 0`, SQLite doesn't wait a disk writting confirmation and therefore writes are requires less time. Try to use `WAL` to some-how emulate multiple writers/pool connection. Another solution can be is use one transaction (=> one writer) for initialization, but I don't know how to force TypeORM for that.

Comment: Thanks for responding. We tried WAL indeed but it didn't make much difference. So we are now thinking of maybe using a migration file, so we can batch / raw call it all.. But that gives a lot of other problems cause the migration file isn't aware of all the tablenames (they are known after a certain API call to multiple brokers).... So I agree with you, that batching / multiple calls would be a lot faster already, but don't know how to fix that with just one app instance

Comment: Also you can try to switch to `better-sqlite`-driver instead of `sqlite3`.

Comment: Having lots of tables isn't optimal for sqlite, no. Every time you first do something with a newly connected database, it's having to parse 3000 table definitions (plus indexes, views, etc )... Use one table for all the stocks, not one per stock.

Comment: @AikonMogwai I am indeed on better-sqlite now, but not much difference :(

Comment: @Shawn do you have any recommendation for database types that are pretty good with this? (was thinking of MongoDB)

Comment: Sqlite would likely be just fine with a reasonable database design.

Comment: Imho, it's not about database design. It doesn't matter how many tables you have in a database. SQLite is not a good choice when you need multiple writers or powerfull analitics (because query planner is not very sophisticated), but it's great if you need mostly read-only store or portable data. This case has a contradiction: ORM is highly recommended for large/complicated projects (3000+ classes) with PostreSQL or Mongo and ORM is redundant for small/simple project where SQLite is enough.

Comment: @AikonMogwai, I agree.

The stock tables will be 99% read only with no JOINS. So I think there is really no simpler setup than having a bunch of tables, each with thousands of rows, that will never JOIN. So replacing sqlite with MySQL or Mongo or whatever, is fine.. But it will not change the uber simple setup of the tables.

Its super flat, also a row will never UPDATE.. Once written, it is a (stock price) fact.. It will not change...